# File google-services.json is missing, but what services?

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, google-play-services

I'm facing issues when using one of the new Firebase features which came out a few days ago. My application has used Firebase before, but now I want to add the storage feature. Therefore I added the dependency to my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
compile 'com.firebase:geofire:1.1.0+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0' }
```

Below I added:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

As I haven't  used the plugin for google-services before, I am missing the **google-servies.json** file. As noted here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#troubleshooting I am supposed to get this file from google by specifying the services the app uses. However, I only use the Places API, while I can only specify "Sign-In", "Cloud Messaging", "Analytics", "App Invites" and "Ad Mob" here: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Comment: mikwee is absolutely right. Good point on that other doc as well! The Firebase version of that is [in the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/gradle/) but we'll get the one you found updated to link to the Firebase version for people using Firebase services.

Comment: You also need to add google services in project level as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you go to this link "https://console.firebase.google.com/project/yourprojectname/overview" when already logged in, you will see a button saying "Add Firebase to your Android app". Click on it and a popup will show up. On step 2 it will give you a download link for the google-servies.json file. Follow the steps and you're done.

Comment: If the download on step 2 doesn't include the "api_key/current_key" you'll need to click on "Manage" from app card in the overview and re-download the file.

Answer (score 4):

mikewee's answer didn't work for me, since I had already gone through the migration to firebase process.

Instead, the instructions here will get you a **google-services.json**: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

To download a **google-service.json** for an Android app:

- Sign in to **Firebase** and open your project.
- Click  and select Project settings.
- In the Your apps card, select the package name of the app you need a        config file for from the list.
- Click **google-services.json**.

and then paste the **google-services.json** file to your project’s **app folder**