# Google-services.json not found

Tags: android, firebase

**I am facing this error**

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot 
>   function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     C:\Users\Kartik\AndroidStudioProjects\barcode\app\src\debug\google-
>   services.json
>    C:\Users\Kartik\AndroidStudioProjects\barcode\app\google-services.json

**I have added this path in build.gradle(project:barcode)**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

**and added this in build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have also added the **google-services.json** file in **project->app** folder but then also it is giving the same error.

Comment: just clean the project and try to rebuild it and tell what happened

Comment: Now also facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem before .
check the json file name and make sure that there is no additional spaces

Comment: yeah, the name of json file was incorrect.
My Mistake :p

Comment: so , Good luck and happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all please make sure that you have followed documentation for firebase and not google developers guidelines and alspo generated Google-services.json for firebase project that is running in your firebase-console, you can see all your running projects in your dashboard in firebase

Make sure you have correct json file, this problem is describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379333/5476209).

You can follow these steps also as per [firebase documentaion](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592).

still if you are all correct and getting errors make sure you have updated **play services** version in your SDK and also put this line in your **app module** `build.gradle` file, to make sure that multidex is unable. Hope you will make something out of it.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```